# Derivative of polar curve

Tags: calculus

We all know a derivative of a function in Cartesian coordinates can be represented (or is defined by) by the slope of a line tangent to the graph. I know that concepts of math are often extended beyond the realm of intuitivity, but I was wondering what the derivative of a polar curve represents, a change in the radius over a change in angle. I'm not convinced it's the tangent line to the graph, because the angle is not a linear measurement and doesn't have units. Does anyone have any intuition for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you seem to have hit the nail on the head!

In a Cartesian coordinates, it makes sense that $\displaystyle \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ would help create a line, because a line is compatible with the horizontal and vertical components of the xy grid.

However, in polar coordinates, a tangent line doesn't really tie well with $r$ and $\theta$ like that, especially when it doesn't pass through the origin.

So how do you find the tangent line to a polar curve, well sorry to let you down, but you'll have to parameterize it first and then go from there. Since tangent *lines* are using Cartesian bases.

Comment: Saketh Malyala thank you! That makes sense that in polar coordinates, because r=theta is not a linear relationship, then the derivative dr/dtheta has little relationship to a tangent line. Do you think the derivative dr/dtheta has any literal meaning in a polar sense? I'm not sure it does, as your explanation proves. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes there is a geometric relationship. for the dy and dx in cartesian functions, the dy points vertically and dx points horizontally. easy to grasp. however, for the "tangent" to $r=f(\theta)$, at $(r_0,\theta_0)$, $d\theta$ is tangent to $r=r_0$, while $dr$ is *perpendicular* to $r=r_0$.

Comment: so it's a differently oriented triangle